# wine: cannot find L"/home/lubuntu/.wine/drive_c/windows/Neko"

Tags: power, linux, ubuntu, windows, terminal

I am an unexperienced Linux user. I am trying to run an exe file in wine on live usb lubuntu 22.04 The problem is that when I try to run it from terminal by pasting the destination along with the command wine (file destination and exe) as shown on screen it gives this output:

> cannot find L"/home/lubuntu/.wine/drive_c/windows/Neko"

Neko is the shortened name for the exe file. How do I run it? Sorry if that is already somewhere. This kind of problem I have looked for solutions, however I did not understood any solution.